# LogCat like view in Eclipse for non Android development

Tags: eclipse, logging

LogCat is a nice tool for Android development. Wonder if similar tool with multi-tab logs filtering exists for normal Java development? Or may be there is some hack to send logs to LogCat from normal Java project?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the same than LogCat, but **[nTail](http://www.certiv.net/products/ntail.html)** is an handy multi-tag log plugin.

[image]

It can be used for any kind of logs.